# Loop over word document paragraphs and tables

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I want to loop over every segment in a sequence.

Example
Document 1

```
Header
Paragraph1
Table1
Paragraph2
Paragraph3
Table2
Footer
```

How can I loop over these segments in a sequence using word interop?

Comment: loop through for what reason, trying to find something ?

Comment: I want to create a new document with some formatting on tables, paragraph